# Getting matches in preg_match not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've been trying to understand how to get `preg_match` to work with the following pattern:

```
\[flexvideo.* id="(?<id>[^"']+)" type="(?<type>[^"']+)".*\]\iU
```

Effectively, I have the following code: `[flexvideo id="" type="" aspect=""]`

which can also be written as: `[flexvideo id='' type='' aspect='']`

Attributes can be in any order.

What I don't understand is when I use the `'` instead of the `"` I get no results that match, where the other doesn't.

Additionally, I'd like the matches to show empty fields if there is no match.

Here is what I've been working with: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/dGA

Comment: You need to use `*` instead of `+` to get empty string matches.

Comment: If you process each tag as a separate sentence (or if there is one), you can just use [`(?<tag_start>\[flexvideo\b\s*|(?!^)\G)\s*(?<attr>[^=\s]+)=(["']?)(?<val>(?:(?!\3).)*)\3(?=[^\/]*(?:\/(?!])[^\/]*)*\/])`](https://regex101.com/r/jS9dE4/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

- ["\'] => " or '
- [^"\']*  => any char excepts " and ' 0 or more times

Code:

```
$str = '[flexvideo id="" type=\'biuahsdiuasd\' aspect="c"]\iU';
$reg = '/\[flexvideo\s+id=["\'](?<id>[^"\']*)["\']\s+type=["\'](?<type>[^"\']*).*?\]/';
preg_match($reg, $str, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [flexvideo id="" type='biuahsdiuasd' aspect="c"]
    [id] => 
    [1] => 
    [type] => biuahsdiuasd
    [2] => biuahsdiuasd
)
```

Comment: it works for the most part, but if you see here http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/dGR there are still some empty arrays. sometimes the sting is in different orders, and has additional attributes